# Why value in child component is not changed after emit from parent?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have a parent component `view-event-component` within child component inside:

```
<app-visitor-component (message)="message($event)" [_event]="event"></app-visitor-component>
```

Inside `view-event-component` there is:

```
  public dataFromChild: any;

  message($event) {
      console.log($event);
      this.dataFromChild = $event;
  }
```

Template `view-event-component` is:

```
{{ dataFromChild }}
```

So, when I push data from parent to child using `@Output` I always get message in:

```
message($event) {
   console.log($event);
}
```

But variable is not showed (rendered) in template:

```
{{ dataFromChild }}
```

There are no errors and warnings.

I use last version of Angular and Mozilla Firefox

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes value is showed when mouse is focused in area where I try to display variable

Comment: I guess problem in rendering and change detection

Comment: if you has in componetn `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` you need `markForCheck()`, see https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: In parent component? I dont have in child and parent component

Comment: Sometime I can see value in template but with delay in 6 seconds

Comment: Could you please provide child parent and child component?

Comment: Please share your code ?

Comment: Could we move to chat, it would be better

Comment: Can you please show code for child component and template as well?

Comment: Lets go to chat please

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

Trigger manually changeDetection:

```
constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

triggerDetecton():void {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

You also should provide a StackBlitz to help us understand better

Comment: I have tried, no changes, could we move to chat I can demonstrate?

Comment: Just share a stackblitz

Comment: It is long way because it has a lot dependencies

Comment: I have any desk access

Comment: Problem is in rendering, it renders so long time chnages of variable

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to understand the behavior. Try to quickfix by redirect the responsability of the data handler to a service.

Comment: Lets go to chat please

Answer (score 0):

try like this in child:

```
message= new EventEmitter<Object>();
messagefunction(event) {
    this.messageEvent.emit(event);
}
```

Comment: I have tried, I get message, but when I pass this message to roaster it is not working

Comment: Lets go to chat please